# Setting up a loop in SQL

Tags: sql, loops

Can someone tell me how to do this as a loop in SQL?

```
update Bank set Report_date_next='2014-02-28' where Reporting_date='2014-01-31'
update Bank set Report_date_next='2014-03-31' where Reporting_date='2014-02-28'
update Bank set Report_date_next='2014-04-30' where Reporting_date='2014-03-31'
update Bank set Report_date_next='2014-05-31' where Reporting_date='2014-04-30'
update Bank set Report_date_next='2014-06-30' where Reporting_date='2014-05-31'
update Bank set Report_date_next='2014-07-31' where Reporting_date='2014-06-30'
```

The list goes on for quite a while so I need a counter on how to find the last cell as well similar to the XlDown in VBA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop in stored procedure in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435195/loop-in-stored-procedure-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're way better off using a `CASE` statement:

```
UPDATE Bank
SET Report_date_next = CASE WHEN Reporting_date = '2014-01-31' THEN '2014-02-28'
                            WHEN Reporting_date = '2014-02-28' THEN '2014-03-31'
                            WHEN ...etc
                        END
```

If you tag your question with the DBMS you're using, there may be an even easier way depending on the functions available to you.

For instance, SQL Server 2012+ you can do:

```
UPDATE Bank
SET report_date_next = EOMONTH(Reporting_date,1)
```

Comment: @SergeKashlik NP, I was able to simplify it a bit farther too.  The `DATEADD` was unnecessary